# Selenium, Get Elements By Xpath - Only grab last 60 elements on page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm having a little trouble working out how I can specify the last 60 elements on a page

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""(//div[@class='hotProductDetails'])""")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```

This code prints every bit of text within those elements on the webpage. But I'm trying to scrape a site that has a 'Load More' button on it.

The 'Load More' button loads 60 more products, and I'd like my code to only grab those products. That way I can stick it all in a loop which clicks the button, grabs the products it loads, append to a Pandas Dataframe and repeats for a set number of iterations.

I've been unable to get code that will do this for me, and once that load more button is pressed a lot of times, grabbing the elements can kill chrome and in turn my script.

```
"(//div[@class='hotProductDetails'])[position() > {} and position() <= {}])".format ((page -1 ) * 50, page * 50)
```

Someone shared this code with me, but it crashes me with this error:

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//div[@class='hotProductDetails'])[position() > {} and position() <= {}])".format ((page -1 ) * 50, page * 50 because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//div[@class='hotProductDetails'])[position() > {} and position() <= {}])".format ((page -1 ) * 50, page * 50' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

This is the first time I've ever had a web-scraping project and used Selenium (which is an amazing package, so impressed with it) and I'm not sure what to do to fix it. I suspect it something to do with the 'page' code, as everything sits on the same webpage which just gets larger as you load more products.

I can share the website I'm scraping if that helps - like I said this is my first scraping project and for a company I just joined. I don't know if this is something they would be upset about me sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting a invalid XPATH selector then something is wrong. There was extra ")" at the end. Below works for me

```
page = 2

xpath_selector = "(//div[@class='hotProductDetails'])[position() > {} and position() <= {}]".format ((page -1 ) * 50, page * 50)
```

Also if you want something like last 60 elements then you can even use below

```
xpath_selector = "(//div[@class='hotProductDetails'])[position() > last() - 60]"
```

Comment: xpath_selector = "(//div[@class='hotProductDetails'])[position() > last() - 60]" worked great, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If the load more is taking elements and appending to the div contents which were initially loaded for the page, why not just keep track of the start and end points for the data?

For instance, if 1 - 10 is loaded by default, if I click "load more" than the div now holds 20 elements but I know I should only be concerned with 11 - 20 etc...?   This is typically how I've solved this problem in the past.

Comment: That's a good idea.. The original div holds 111 elements, then 60 more each time. So I could just grab the last 60 in my post.text. The only reason I thought this would be better is because the get_elements can sometimes crash Chrome once the webpage gets quite large